# Will requests to an aliased domain be cached by the browser?

Tags: http, optimization, browser, dns, cdn

If I'm using a CDN to deliver images on an image-heavy page and I'm using a set of CNAME records pointing to the same CDN domain for faster loading, will images served (and cached by the browser) from one alias by found in the browser cache when served from another alias?

More simply, if cdn1.example.com and cdn2.example.com point to the same domain, will a browser be smart enough to load an image served from cdn1.example.com from the cache when subsequently called from cdn2.example.com?

My understanding is that this scenario will work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it won't work. Browsers cache resources on the basis of their URLs. If the URLs are different, caching doesn't work.

See ["Serve resources from a consistent URL" in Page Speed's recommendations](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#duplicate_resources).

You should use the same domain shard for each image. Depending on your backend technology, implement a simple function that computes the domain number based on the image name. A simple solution is `hashcode(imageName) % n` where n is the number of domain shards. This way, you don't have to remember which image falls under which domain bucket.